# how to display html effect for the plaintext with html tags

Tags: html, css, tinymce, strip-tags

I'm using TinyMCE in the text editor to style the input text

while I'm inserting that text input into the database it is stored with Html tags like below

```
<p>Hello</p> <strong>buddy</strong>
```

when I retrieve the data from the database, it displaying the text with Html tags only and not displaying the HTML effect

How can I get the text with HTML effect!

Any idea or any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to add a codesample which is HTML in your case. But when you save it and render the tinyMCE editor again it interprets it as HTML content and not text content. Kindly correct me if my understanding of your question is wrong

If i am right in understanding your problem, below is your solution

1. You need to enter the HTML block of code via a plugin which is codesample rather than directly pasting it in the editor text box. Here is the link for your reference https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/codesample/
2. When you are rerendering the HTML block in editor or elsewhere. There are chances that it might still interpret it as HTML. To resolve that you'll have to escape HTML characters before rendering

If you can help me with a pen ( https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/ ), I'll be able to give more insights based on your usecase

Cheers!

[UPDATE post clarification of doubt]

You can use a script to first capture the content and set the html via JS script, something like below

```
<div class="content_from_editor">
  <strong>Hello</strong>
</div>
<script>
 var htmlData = document.getElementById('app');
 document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = htmlData;
</script>
```

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for your quick reply
Actually, 
I have input text area, where users allow to give some text paragraph, in their paragraph they need to make the text look bold,.etc.
I used TinyMCE editor to allow the users to write paragraphs in bold.
when I try to store that paragraph text into the database it storing with HTML tags.
like <strong>Hello</strong> 

when i retrieve that data from the database it displays the plain text with HTML tags

I'm not getting HTML effect, for this what I have to do

in above-posted question, HTML tags are not displayed sorry for that!

Comment: Understood. Are you seeing the html tags as plain text inside the editor itself or or on some other part of the app where you are displaying the content created using the editor?

Comment: yeah! I need to display the text with HTML effect on some other page by retreiving through database.

in database base text is stored with html tags like 

<strong>hello</strong>

i need to display that data with HTML effect by removing tags.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the technique that worked just fine for me